# How can I create function which contains an ODE system and its numeric solution?

Tags: functions, differential-equations

I have created a function like the following, which contains an [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) system. And I want to know the effect of different parameters.

```
    myodessystem[k1_, k2_, time_] := Module[{odes, y, x, sol, myfun},
      odes = {y'[x] == k1 y[x] Cos[k2 x + y[x]], y[0] == 1};
      sol = NDSolve[odes, y, {x, 0, time}];
      myfun = y[x] /. sol
      ]
```

But I can not get the solutions I want:

```
mysolve = myodessystem[1, 1, 30]

(* {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 30.}}, <>][x$12879]} *)
```

And it does not work when I assign a value to the result function:

```
    mysolve[10]

(* {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 30.}}, <>][x$12879]}[10] *)
```

How can I get the solution of the ODE and get the result value when I assign a value to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note change at end of your function... you might also want to add checks to ensure that there *was* a solution so as not to return a nonsense function.

```
myodessystem[k1_, k2_, time_] := 
  Module[{odes, y, x, sol, myfun}, 
   odes = {y'[x] == k1 y[x] Cos[k2 x + y[x]], y[0] == 1};
   sol = NDSolve[odes, y, {x, 0, time}];
   myfun = First[y /. sol]];

mysolve = myodessystem[1, 1, 30];

mysolve[1]

(* 0.991387 *)
```

Per *Michael*'s cogent comment, this can be condensed to:

```
myodessystem[k1_, k2_, time_] := 
  Module[{odes, y, x, sol, myfun}, 
   odes = {y'[x] == k1 y[x] Cos[k2 x + y[x]], y[0] == 1};
   NDSolveValue[odes, y, {x, 0, time}]
   ];
```

Comment: Also, `myfun = NDSolveValue[odes, y, {x, 0, time}]` seems appropriate in this context (and skip `sol` altogether).

Comment: @MichaelE2: Added edit - good point.

Answer (score 4):

What the OP is trying to code is already in *Mathematica* in the form of [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html).

```
myodessystem = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[x] == k1 y[x] Cos[k2 x + y[x]], y[0] == 1},
   y, {x, 0, time}, {k1, k2, time}]
(*  ParametricFunction[<>]  *)

mysolve = myodessystem[1, 1, 30];
mysolve[1]
(*  0.991387  *)
```

Comment: Nice - don't recall coming across that, +1

Comment: Thank you very much for excellent answer.

Comment: @ZihuGuo You're welcome.